# JPA persistent entity without persist() instruction

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm

I've got this JPAServiceImpl method:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void createPageContent(SellerContent content, long userId) {

    Seller s = em.find(Seller.class,userId);
    content.setSeller(s);

    content.setSeller(s);
    s.addContent(content);
}
```

It works, but I wonder how it can work since there isn't any
`em.merge(seller)` or `em.persist(content)`.

Seller has got CascadeType.ALL with SellerContent relationship.

Could you please explain me if this is a normal behaviour? I would have written both `em.merge(seller)` and `em.persist(content)`. Is it wrong?

For example, I wrote this method:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void createFeedback(CartLine cartLine, String feedbackString) {
    Product product = cartLine.getProduct();

    Feedback feedback = new Feedback();
    feedback.setFeedbackContent(feedbackString);
    feedback.setCartLine(cartLine);
    cartLine.setFeedback(feedback);
    product.getFeedbacks().add(feedback);
    feedback.setProduct(product);

    em.persist(feedback);
    em.merge(cartLine);
    em.merge(product);
}
```

In this method I wrote merge and persist instructions. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works beacuse your `Seller` object is loaded via entity manager in the same transaction. At runtime it will be replaced by a proxy object. Each change on this object will be automaticaly  persisted at the end of transaction. You can check it very easy: at runtime make a brakepoint in your `createPageContent` method, then check actual type of `Seller s` variable. It will be a proxy that is necessary for following things:

- Detect every change on `Seller s` state (for example `s.addContent(content)`). Persist these changes at the end of transaction.
- Load lazy relations. Imagine your `Seller` has list of `Owner`. By default at runtime this list will be empty. It will be loaded exactly at the moment when you do `s.getOwners().iterator()`.

So normally you need to call `em.persist()` only for instances that was created using `new` keyword. Most of time even this is not necessary: you can attach new object `A` to persisted object `B` and then call `em.persist(B)`. `A` will be persisted by cascade.

Second block of the code:

- I think you can safely remove `em.merge` calls. Merge only neccessary when you do `CartLine mergedCartline = em.merge(cartLine); mergedCartline.doSomething()`.
- You can remove `em.persist(feedback)` call if : a) `CartLine cartLine` always loaded via entity manager; b) `cartLine.feedback` property can be persisted by cascade (depends on your mapping).

Comment: @MaksymDemidas Thank you for you explanation :) But I've got a doubt: you said that I can call `em.persist()` for instances that were created using new keyword. I use `Feedback feedback = new Feedback();` and then `cartLine.setFeedback(feedback);`. If I understood, I could remove `em.persist(feedback)` if I got CascadeType=PERSIST above CartLine relationship with Feedback; am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Since your Entity is in the managed state, you do not have to call `percist()` methode.